# Hashtag keeps appearing when I open Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, href

I am not sure why this keeps happening. I searched how to remove hashtags from the URL and found many answers. All of them was no help as all they simply did was remove the hashtag, but I had to refresh the page. And even then that still did not help. My problem is that the hashtag appears when I click on this anchor tag:

```
echo '<a  href="?id='.$row['id'].'" <-- here is what I am trying to add to the URL, but the hashtag appears. id="smallbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#small"  data-modal="small">';
```

Here is the javascript I used to try and fix my problem, but no success (Also was told to use it in the `<head>`.):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
// remove fragment as much as it can go without adding an entry in browser history:
window.location.replace("#");

// slice off the remaining '#' in HTML5:    
if (typeof window.history.replaceState == 'function') {
  history.replaceState({}, '', window.location.href.slice(0, -1));
}
</script>
```

And I don't know if this is the problem, but I use this to open the modal and put the anchor tag href in the URL:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window.location.hash).modal('show');
   $('a[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(){
      window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
   });
});
</script>
```

My goal is to try to put that href in the URL as parameter and so far I am having a hard time getting it that work. Any help on this is gladly appreciated!

Comment: you need the the id of  `href="?id='.$row['id'].'"`? if not need then please put `href=javascript:void(0)`

Comment: @MohsinMarui Oh yes, I do need the id. I am using the GET Method in my php. Thank you for that answer though.

Answer (score 0):

In the click event callback, the line where you set `window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');` , this will cause the a '#' to be prefixed before the content you set, ie, the value of href attribute.

Comment: Ahh I see. So is there a way I can prevent that from happening? @samizzy

Comment: I am not sure but maybe you can use this instead `window.location.origin+=$(this).attr('href')`

Comment: this actually created the same page within the modal. It was like two pages in one.

Comment: oh that shouldnt happen, now window.location.origin should be your desired url, oh ok i get it , do this `window.location.href= window.location.origin + $(this).attr('href');`

Comment: Ok. Two things just happened. At first it did the same thing, then it redirected me to the localhost dashboard.

Comment: can you try printing the formed url using console.log(window.location.origin + $(this).attr('href')) , what is the url formed?  is that the url you need?

Comment: Sure thing. The URL formed is this: `www.example.com#?id=10` and expected: `www.example.com?id=10`. I also read this might help, but I am not sure how to implement it:  `window.location.hash.replace("#", "");`

Comment: From what i see the url printed is correct (desired), however the url formed contained # i have no idea how (make sure you dont set location.hash anymore)..also what does your get method return? Another thing if  you use window.location.href the entire web page will be forwarded to that url ie,the page will loose state(modal will dissapear etc), maybe you want to use ajax for getting  the response?. for eg $.get or $.ajax, this will also free you from this #trouble.

Comment: The get method returns the id of `10` in which I use for a php query. With ajax, is it possible to get that value with the get method?

Comment: I meant what does the server side code returns in response, but judging from your answer i think user information is returned and yes with ajax you can do it, very easy to use, this site explains it clearly -https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Comment: thank you so much. Although I am fairly new to this, I might ask another question on SO.